# MVC2 Quote handling / escaping within a style attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have no idea how to handle this code within a style attribute. How do I correctly code this markup or properly escape it? I could use a string.format and emit the entire div but that seems like an awkward solution.

(I figured all those slant brackets would pose an issue in this posting so I am including an image.)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this all the time in my editor as well, for some reason, it doesn't color the attributes properly *sometimes* in CSS and JS.  However, the attribute that you are spitting out will should still perform like you are expecting.

Comment: I also had an issue with my xhtml inline closing on the div. IE was nesting divs within my foreach. Added a separate closing tag and all is well. Thanks!